# How to remove the whitespace and convert lower to upper case using Regex in C#?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have tried the below code to remove the whitespace between the string. But it is removing whitespace at the beginning and at the end of the string. Also I tried to convert the lower case letter to the upper case. It is also not working.

```
string source = "AN -7782";
source = Regex.Replace(source, @"^[A-Z]+\s+$","");
```

My Input source string will be like "`An- 1234", "aN-1234", "an-1234", "AN -1234", "AND - 1234", "aNd -1234",...` whatever it may be. I need the output as

```
"AN-1234" or "AND-1234".
```

Comment: Regex doesn't really make sense for this. You could just remove all spaces, and then uppercase the string.

Comment: Remove all spaces, `\t` and convert characters to uppercase using string methods. There is no need for a regex here...

Comment: It would look like `source.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();`

Comment: I need to do this using regex alone.

Comment: Any reason why? Regex can't uppercase a string.

Comment: In many languages usage of `\U` in the replace pattern converts the group to upper case, but it's not supported in .NET: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ae2778b-2e1a-4e3b-8471-3fe97e268f72/does-u-convert-to-uppercase-work-in-net-regex?forum=regexp

Otherwise you could have searched for `(\w+)\s*\-\s*(\w+)` and replace it with `\U$1-\U$2`. But `\U` is not supported in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can simply try like this:</strike>

```
var str = " mY StRiNg".Trim().ToUpper();
```

or you can use the Replace method like

```
var str = " mY StRiNg".Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();
```

Comment: I need my output as "MYSTRING"

Comment: @VADIVELNATARAJANuser2505309:- Then you can use the `replace method` see the demo here: http://ideone.com/2xwgWM

Comment: i need to do this using regex alone

Comment: @VADIVELNATARAJANuser2505309:- Why you want a sword when you can perform things using needle? You really dont require regex for this task.